# Stretch time series efficiently in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to stretch time series to different length using SQL efficiently. Suppose I have the following data:

[SQLFiddle (PostgreSQL)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/d759b/1)

```
-- drop table if exists time_series;

create table time_series (
  id serial,
  val numeric)
;

insert into time_series (val) values 
     (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), 
     (5), (4), (3), (2), (1);
```

This time series has length 11 and I would like to stretch it to length 15 in such way that sum of values in stretched time series is the same as sum of values in the original time series. I have a solution which is not efficient:

```
select
  new_id,
  sum(new_val) as new_val
from
  (
    select 
      id, 
      val/15.0 as new_val,
      ceil(row_number() over(order by id, gs) / 11.0) as new_id
    from 
      time_series 
      cross join (select generate_series(1, 15) gs) gs 
  ) raw_data
group by
    new_id
order by
  new_id
;
```

This would first create a table with 15*11 rows and then collapsing it back into 15 rows.

While this works well for small time series, performance gets significantly worse with longer time-series. Given I would like to stretch 2,000 rows into 3,000, than the query has to generate 6M rows first (takes 30 seconds on my laptop).

Test data:

```
insert into time_series (val) select generate_series(1, 1000);
insert into time_series (val) select generate_series(1000, 1, -1);
```

Is there more efficient solution in SQL with same results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. To stretch time series with 5 elements into time series with 30 elements while keeping total sum of values, you can use:

```
with time_series (id, val) as (values
  (1, 1),
  (2, 2),
  (3, 3),
  (4, 2),
  (5, 1)
)

, mapping_to_old_ts_ids as (
  select 
    gs as new_id,
    case when mod(((gs - 1) * otsl + 1), ntsl) <> 0 then ((gs - 1) * otsl + 1) / ntsl + 1 else ((gs - 1) * otsl + 1) / ntsl end as old_id_start,
    case mod(((gs - 1) * otsl + 1), ntsl) when 0 then ntsl else mod(((gs - 1) * otsl + 1), ntsl) end as old_id_start_piece,
    case when mod((gs * otsl), ntsl) <> 0 then (gs * otsl) / ntsl + 1 else (gs * otsl) / ntsl end as old_id_end,
    case mod((gs * otsl), ntsl) when 0 then ntsl else mod((gs * otsl), ntsl) end as old_id_end_piece,
    ntsl
  from 
    (select generate_series(1, ntsl) as gs, ntsl from (select 30 as ntsl) a) new_time_series
    cross join (select count(*) as otsl from time_series) old_time_series_length    
)

select
  new_id,
    case 
      when old_id_start = old_id_end then (old_id_end_piece - old_id_start_piece + 1) / ntsl::numeric * ts1.val 
      when old_id_start <> old_id_end then (ntsl::numeric - old_id_start_piece +1 ) / ntsl::numeric * ts1.val + coalesce((old_id_end_piece / ntsl::numeric * ts2.val), 0) end
from
  mapping_to_old_ts_ids oid
  join time_series ts1 on (oid.old_id_start = ts1.id)
  left join time_series ts2 on (oid.old_id_end = ts2.id)
order by 
  new_id
```

The above query is already simplified version of my original, more verbose query. If you are interested, this is how I gradually figured out the solution (trying to stretch 5 rows into 8):

```
with time_series (id, val) as (values
  (1, 1),
  (2, 2),
  (3, 3),
  (4, 2),
  (5, 1)
)

/* The basic idea is to divide every element into 8 pieces and then aggregate it 
   back by 5 elements. When trying to stretch 5 into 8, we will have 5 * 8 = 40
   elements. For every element in new time series we can calculate what is the id
   of first and last piece. */    
, piece_start_end as (
  select 
    gs as new_id,
    (gs - 1) * 5 + 1 as piece_start,
    gs * 5 as piece_end
  from 
    generate_series(1, 8) gs
)


/* No we need to calculate where exactly in the old time series we have beginning
and end of pieces. E.g. 1st element of new time series starts in element 1 at position 1
and ends in element 1 at position 5. 2nd element of new time series starts in element 1
at position 6 and ends in element 2 at position 2. */
, mapping_to_old_ts_ids as (
  select 
    *, 
    case when mod(piece_start, 8) <> 0 then piece_start / 8 + 1 else piece_start / 8 end as old_id_start,
    case mod(piece_start, 8) when 0 then 8 else mod(piece_start, 8) end as old_id_start_piece,

    case when mod(piece_end, 8) <> 0 then piece_end / 8 + 1 else piece_end / 8 end as old_id_end,
    case mod(piece_end, 8) when 0 then 8 else mod(piece_end, 8) end as old_id_end_piece
  from 
    piece_start_end
)

/* In final step we just need to assign final value to new time series by taking
 appropriate number of pieces from old time series elements. */


select
    new_id,

    old_id_start,
    old_id_start_piece,
    ts1.val as old_id_start_val,

    old_id_end,
    old_id_end_piece,
    ts2.val as old_id_end_val,

    case 
      when old_id_start = old_id_end then (old_id_end_piece - old_id_start_piece + 1) / 8.0 * ts1.val 
      when old_id_start <> old_id_end then (8 - old_id_start_piece +1 ) / 8.0 * ts1.val + coalesce((old_id_end_piece / 8.0 * ts2.val), 0) end

from
  mapping_to_old_ts_ids oid
  join time_series ts1 on (oid.old_id_start = ts1.id)
  left join time_series ts2 on (oid.old_id_end = ts2.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query without cross join.

First we generate `ts1` subquery with intervals of values then join it with a new sequence. And in the select list interpolate (linear) new ID to the joined interval of values - `new_val`.

Also in this query we use `+1-1` to transform `1,2,3,...` sequence to `0,1,2,....`

```
select 
  gs as new_id,
  Sval+(Eval-SVal)*((gs.gs-1) /(100.0/(11.0-1))+1-ts1.ID) as new_val,
  SVal as StartInterval,
  EVal as EndInterval       
from 
  (Select generate_series(1, 100) gs) gs 
  left join
  (select T1.ID, T1.Val SVal,T2.Val EVal
     FROM
     time_series T1
     JOIN time_series T2 ON T1.Id=T2.ID-1) ts1 
   ON floor((gs.gs-1) /(100.0/(11.0-1)))+1=ts1.ID 
order by
gs
```

Comment: This is definitely fast, but it does something different. I need that sum of `new_val` is the same as sum of `val` in the original time series after stretch (and I should have mentioned that in my answer). While my query returns `1000999.99` your will return `1502249.50`. Because SQLFiddle is down, I added test data for time series with 2.000 rows to my question.